# How to create a server sent event using spring web-flux

Tags: spring-webflux, server-sent-events

I am using Spring Webflux to allow for sending HTTP requests in my backend. For this purpose, I have implemented a service, which contains the two methods `getData_1()`and `getData_2()`, following the subsequent pattern:

```
  public ExampleData getData_1() {
    return webClient.get()
      .uri("/exampleData")
      .retrieve()
      .bodyToMono(ExampleData.class).block();
  }
```

What I would like to achieve now, is to implement a REST controller with a single endpoint, handling a GET request. Inside this single controller method, I would like to call both `getData_1()` and `getData_2()` and inform my frontend once either of these methods has returned.

I have tried to figure out how to do this, but I haven't really had any luck. To the best of my knowledge, I think this could work somewhat like this:

```
  @GetMapping
  public Flux<ExampleData> getExampleData() {
    return Flux.just(myService.getData_1(), myService.getData_2());
  }
```

I want to create a Server Sent Event once either of the methods `getData_1()` or `getData_2()` has returned and, thus, let my server inform my client about this status. I know I am still a bit far away from this solution and would, therefore, like some advice as on how to approach this problem.

Comment: Typically Server Sent Events are used to subscribe to continuous stream of data. In your case this is just a single call to the endpoint and only one `ExampleData` is expected. In this case it should not be `Flux` but `Mono`. Also, there is no reason to block after you got response from the WebClient.

Comment: I thought it would have to be a flux, since I am combining the two calls `getData_1()` and `getData_2()`. If I replace the Flux with a Mono, wouldn't I only emit once, whereas I want to emit an event after each of the calls has completed

Comment: you are taking 2 publishers but want to return only one. What about Server Sent Event? It looks like this is a simple endpoint and not SSE.

Answer (score 0):

To return the first available result you can use `Mono.firstWithSignal` that will pick the first Mono to emit the signal.

```
@GetMapping
public Mono<ExampleData> getExampleData() {
    return Mono.firstWithSignal(myService.getData_1(), myService.getData_2());
}
```

Also, there is no reason to `block` after getting results from WebClient.

```
public Mono<ExampleData> getData_1() {
    return webClient.get()
      .uri("/exampleData")
      .retrieve()
      .bodyToMono(ExampleData.class);
}
```